# Xamarin Async List Cant Display

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, asynchronous, xamarin

I have a few string that i have made available within the class scope. I initialize them in the Dis() method. I get the values for these values from the Local database like this - `var ra = await App.Database.GetProfileAsync(email, password);`

The problem is that, when i run the app, i cant see the list items in my list. There is no error as such but i think that my app is being executed before it initializes the string.

Below is the Entire Activity code (.cs) -

```
using LoginSystem.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LoginSystem.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class UserProfile : ContentPage
    {
        string email;
        string password;
        string username;
        string gender;
        string address;
        string postal;
        string province;
        string country;


        public UserProfile(string e, string p)
        {
            email = e;
            password = p;
            Dis();
            //InitializeComponent();

            //this.BindingContext = new User_Profiles();

            var title = new Label
            {
                Text = "My Profile",
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };

            List<string> Details = new List<string>
            {
                username,
                email,
                gender,
                address,
                postal,
                province,
                country
            };

            ListView articlesView = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = Details
            };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.CadetBlue,
                Padding = 30,
                Spacing = 10,
                Children = { title,articlesView }
            };

        }

        async public void Dis()
        {
                var ra = await App.Database.GetProfileAsync(email, password);
                await DisplayAlert("Country", ra.Country + "!", "OK");
                username = ra.Username;
                email = ra.Username;
                gender = ra.Gender;
                address = ra.Address;
                postal = ra.Postal;
                province = ra.Province;
                country = ra.Country;

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say which is the problem because I think there are lots of problems in your code

1- you should use MVVM... take a look to [Introduction to MVVM](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Introduction-to-MVVM)

2- email, passowrd, username... should be properties with `{get; set;}`

3- you should implement INPC, maybe with `Fody`

4- you should bind a `ObservableCollection` to the `ListView`, not a `List`

Here some help

[Data Binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/)